# make logger.isDebugEnabled() false in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I want to false the condition for " `logger.isDebugEnabled()`" in Groovy

this is my code.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertyResolver;

public class Sample{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sample.class);


    public void checkcode(String scope) {

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("some message ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it depends on logger provider that you are using behind slf4j. for example if you are using log4j - normally you could set log level with log4j.properties file.

Comment: for   **slf4j **  bro

Comment: slf4j itself is just a facade for a real logger. the only logger provider in slf4j - slf4j-simple - https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html parameters could set through system properties or through simplelogger.properties